# Proving $f(n) \ge h(n)$ for all natural n's

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

Can you guys help me with a proof to this equation?

I need to prove that $f(n) \geq h(n)$ for all natural $n$'s.

$$\begin{align}
h(n) &= 3^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} + (-2)^{n-1}\\
f(n) &= f(n-1) + 6\cdot f(n-2)\\
f(0) &= 2\\
f(1) &= 18
\end{align}
$$

So the original problem was to find a function $h(n)$ that suits this equation $f(n) \geq h(n) \geq 3^{n+1} - 2^n$. I already proved that my function $h(n)$ works for $h(n) \geq 3^{n+1} - 2^n$ but I need to prove $f(n) \ge h(n)$ as well.

From the induction hypothesis, we know that $f(n) \geq h(n)$ and $f(n+1) \geq h(n+1)$. Right now, I need to prove induction step $f(n+2)\geq h(n+2)$ by induction so that the proof is complete and we may surely say that $f(n)\geq h(n)$ for all natural $n$'s.

I tried changing $f(n+2)$ into $f(n+1) + 6\cdot f(n)$ and then proving that $$\begin{align} f(n+1) + 6\cdot f(n) \ge 3^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} + (-2)^{n-1}
3^{n+2} - 2^{n} \\ +(-2)^{n} + 6 \cdot 3^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} +(-2)^{n-1} \ge 3^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} + (-2)^{n-1} \end{align}
$$ which should be equal to $$\begin{align} 3^{n+3} - 2^{n+2} + (-2)^{n+1} \ge 3^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} + (-2)^{n-1} \end{align}
$$ but that doesn't seem to be working? Any idea where I'm doing a mistake?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I hope I summarized my problem + thought process better now

Comment: I edited the first part of your question to include MathJax, I suggest you do the same for the last paragraph that is completely unreadable. I don't even know how to edit it because I don't understand where one equation ends and another begins.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference